# Cannot resolve symbol 'val' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors

I'm beginning with the Kotlin language on Android Studio. When I want to create a "val", an error appears : Cannot resolve symbol 'val'. Same issue for transaction.replace ...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Object HomeFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // injecter le fragment dans notre container fragment_container

        val transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragment);
        //Série de transaction pour pouvoir manipuler les fragments

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not Kotlin file, but Java.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is a Java file, and Java does not have the `val` keyword.

You will need to start again in Kotlin, e.g. with the line `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { ... }`